# e.preventdefault and asp.net login form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, node.js

I am trying to submit the asp.net login form only if the https.get function does not produce an error. If it returns an error, I do not want the login form submitted. When I call e.preventDefault() the login page just refreshes without logging the user in.

Why is this?

```
var loginForm = $('form');
var https = require("https");
var url = 'https://examplesite.com/';


loginForm.on('submit', function (e) {
        var loginSubmit = this;
        e.preventDefault();
            https.get(url, function (res) {
                res.resume();
                loginSubmit.submit();
            }).on('error', function () {
                // display error, do not login
            });
});
```

Comment: It's part of node.js. I am 'pinging' the server before submitting the login request. But asp.net will not submit the form with the code above.

Comment: I don't get it...is this code running on client side or server side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the `loginForm` is the actual form, the $('form') in jQuery. Which is the same as `loginSubmit` in your function.

See, when the submit() event is raised, you call the function inside, which calls `loginSubmit.submit()` again. Is it a problem?

You can try bind the function to the submit button's click event.

Need more information about `res.resume()`. And can you please give us where your `loginForm` variable comes from?

---

UPDATE:

I would bind to the click event of the submit button.

```
$(document).on('click','btn#submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // make the get call
    $.get(url)
         .done(function(){
             // success callback => submit the form.
             $('form').submit();
         })
         .fail(function(){
             // fail callback => display error.
         });
});
```

I don't know much about your `https` call. And I am also not very clear about that your  `res.resume()`. But you should have some clue now.

Comment: Yes, loginForm is $('form') in jQuery. I am basically trying to run the login form through that https function so that if it returns true then it submits the login, or false, will not.

Comment: Is there any special reason you did not use jQuery to run that https function? Like `$.get(url).done(//success).fail(//fail)`. But I am concerned about calling `loginSubmit.submit()` inside the your submit callback function.

Comment: Good question, I should probably use that instead. How would I halt the login submission until I get a true or false from the get request?

Comment: detach the event from loginform onSubmit using `.off()`. Attach it again when you get a response

Comment: That is why I suggest bind to the button click event. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on your example .. I'm having a tough time following.